# How Do I Compile a Smart Contract from GitHub?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-compile

Our Smart Contract developer has provided our smart contract repo via GitHub
The GitHub repo has the following folders:
-keys
-scripts
-src
And these files:
-.gitignore
-Disclaimer.md
-LICENSE
-README.md
-terms.md

In my Mist wallet (v 0.9.2) I have a section to paste my solidity code but the folders have many files

How do I compile and deploy my smart contract?

Comment: @pabloruiz55 Is it safe to share my GitHub repo with another developer who wants to quote on a security audit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a folder name "contracts" with the .sol files in there.
Those are the files you should be compiling and deploying.

**Anyways, it is impossible to tell which files should actually be deployed without looking at the source code.**

The person who developed the contracts should be the one deploying them, and if for some reason he is not available, at least get another Solidity developer to review the contracts and deploy them.